# CSS media-queries issue

Tags: html, css

I've have an issue that I didn't have before with media-queries. I have this issue mainly on mobile devices in Chrome and Opera, but do not have in Safari and Firefox.

I've a button which has `display` property set to `none` for devices with screen more than 769px and set to `inline-block` by default. But the most of the browsers do not change property to `inline-block` for devices with screen less than 769px. Here is a pseudo-code:

CSS:

```
.btn_play {
 display: inline-block;
 width:21.875%;
 border-radius:50%;
 background: #F7F7F7;
 font-size: 0;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-align:center;
 color: inherit;
 vertical-align: middle;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 22;
}

@media (min-width: 320px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .btn_play {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .btn_play_desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 769px) and (orientation: landscape){
  .btn_play {
    display: none;
  }
  .btn_play_desktop {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` tag in your page ?